# How to Determine Existence of Turing Reducible Languages?

Tags: computability, reductions

Are *finite* and *recursive* instances of $L$ possible with the following constraints?

$\text{L $\subseteq$ {0,1}*}$ and $L \leq HALT \leq \overline L$ where $\overline L = \{\text{ x $\in$ {0,1}* : x $\notin$ L }\}$.

**NOTE:** Raphael and Yuval kindly pointed out that I was overlooking $\overline L$ is undecidable. Aside from this oversight, are there any *other* issues, e.g. conceptual misunderstandings, logical fallacies, etc. in the explanation below?

As I understand it:

1. A finite instance of $L$ is possible. Since the language is finite, an evaluating Turing Machine (TM) could not loop indefinitely on input, and consequently would halt either in an "accept" or "reject" state. Since the language stops on all inputs, it is recursive and thus can be reduced to $HALT$, which is recursively enumerable.
2. Since a finite instance (which is recursive) is possible, logically a recursive $L$ must also be possible.

Comment: You are ignoring that $\overline{L}$ needs to be *undecidable*.

Comment: @Raphael is my understanding that $\overline L$ includes all strings not included in the finite $L$ -- hence $\overline L$ is infinite -- and therefore undecidable, correct?

Comment: @BrandeisKing, check the definition of undecidable again.  Infinite doesn't imply undecidable!

Comment: Indeed. Many infinite sets decidable; in fact, finite (and co-finite) sets are very boring (in terms of computational complexity) and fall below regular languages in complexity. All of the classes you'll meet during the usual courses are harder!

Comment: [Undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem), as I understand, means anything that is not in $R$ but in $RE$ or not in $RE$. When I apply this to infinite sets (countable or otherwise), per my understanding, infinite sets have the capacity to loop indefinitely -- thus placing them in $RE$ (or undecidable) category. But I believe @Raphael points out, that infinite sets are in fact decidable or in $R$. Therefore, I've clearly misunderstood something. Is my understanding of undecidable wrong or the assumption that all infinite sets have the capacity to loop indefinitely?

Comment: 1) Sets don't "loop". I can't imagine where you're getting this from. 2) *Some* infinite sets are decidable, e.g. those in REG, CFL, CSL, R. -- Yes, you clearly misunderstood something. Go back to the definitions of (semi-)decidability.

Comment: @Raphael My previous comment was poorly phrased; allow me to clarify. Infinite sets themselves do not have the capacity to loop indefinitely, but rather the Turing Machines that attempt to decide the set have the capacity to loop (or evaluate) indefinitely and ultimately may. The way I currently think about it (which apparently is incorrect) is that if a language is infinite, the TM at best can recognize a language since there is input upon which the TM could/would evaluate indefinitely. Do you see where the hole or flaw in my understanding is?

Comment: @BrandeisKing You still have not accepted that while finiteness implies decidability the reverse does not hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To narrow down the search space, consider what you know about closure properties and HPL.

1. The class of decidable languages $R$ is closed against complement.
2. HPL is not in $R$.

You can conclude that $L \not\in R$;¹ otherwise, $\overline{L} \in R$ and therefore $\mathrm{HPL} \not\leq_T \overline{L}$.

On the other end, you need that $L \in RE$ (the set of semi-decidable languages) -- otherwise $L \not\leq_T \mathrm{HPL}$.

In combination, you need $L \in RE \setminus R$ which answers your question².

---

1. In particular, $L$ can not be finite since all such languages are decidable. The decider just checks a hard-coded table of all words in the language. With the same table you can also decide the complement.
2. Note how this implies $\overline{L} \not\in R$ which is enough for $HPL \leq_T \overline{L}$.

Comment: Thanks for cogent explanation; it was very helpful. However, I'd like to clarify one aspect of your answer. You wrote that "this implies $\overline L \notin R$," which as I understand leaves open the possibility of it being in $RE$. But since $L \in RE$  and if $\overline L \in RE$ that would mean $L \in R$ which is not possible per the constraints. Therefore is it safe to assume that $\overline L \notin RE$?

Comment: @BrandeisKing Yes, that's a further conclusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified your notion of reduction, so I'm assuming a computable oracle reduction. Any language reducible to a computable language is computable. HPL (usually known as HALT) is not computable. Hence HPL cannot be reduced to $\overline{L}$ for any computable $L$.

Comment: Adding that the set of recursive functions/languages is (almost trivially) closed against complement, this does indeed provide the answer.

Comment: @Yuval Thanks for your explanation; however, I don't fully understand the conclusion that "$HALT$ cannot be reduced to $\overline L$ for any computable $L$". By "not computable" do you mean not recursive, but recursively enumerable or not recursively enumerable?

Comment: Computable and recursive mean exactly the same thing.